# Login validation always progressing well

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to make simple login validation in c# using php script.

I've made brand new mysql database:

```
login: "admin_dane"
database: "admin_dane"
password: "password"
```

`users` table:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | login | password |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | test  | test     |
+----+-------+----------+
|    |       |          |
+----+-------+----------+
|    |       |          |
+----+-------+----------+
```

C#:

```
byte[] bD = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("login={0}&haslo={1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.TabIndex));
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://password.com/check.php");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Login";
request.ContentLength = bD.Length;
System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(bD, 0, bD.Length);
stream.Close();
System.Net.HttpWebResponse odp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(odp.GetResponseStream());
string zaw = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
odp.Close();


if (zaw.Equals("1"))
MessageBox.Show("nice");
else
MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
```

PHP:

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin_dane", "password");
mysql_select_db("admin_dane");
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$zap = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` where (login = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($zap);
if ($r['id'] >= 0)
echo '1';
?>
```

And I dont know why it returns `nice` every time. No matter what is the input it says like validation is successfull. Can you tell me where is gaffe?

Comment: What is the value of $r['id'] when the login should fail?  If it is 0, then you will always echo '1';

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.